How to fill 2D array in C in order without index specification?
Trying to code the laplace expansion as i'm learning it in college and i'm stuck when it comes to getting the minor matrix of a big matrix. This are always square matrices and the minor matrix is always 1 size less than the big matrix, such that: matrix = nxn => minor = (n-1)x(n-1).
In this part of the code I get the minor such that for an element 'a' of the first row of the matrix the minor consist of all the values that are NOT in the same row or column as element 'a':
    float minor[matrixDimension-1][matrixDimension-1];

    for (i = 0; i < matrixDimension; i++) {

        for (j = 1; j < matrixDimension; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < matrixDimension; k++) {
                
                if(k != i) {
                    minor[j-1][k-1] = matrix[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("minor: \n");
        printf("%f, ", minor[0][0]);
        printf("%f, \n", minor[0][1]);
        printf("%f, ", minor[1][0]);
        printf("%f, \n", minor[1][1]);
    }

I want the matrix "minor" to always be filled with the correct matrix[j][k] values but in the left to right, top to bottom order.
When testing with a 3x3 matrix and a 2x2 minor, the minor is only correct in the first iteration of the first for loop, since this line is the best i could come up for filling minor minor[j-1][k-1] = matrix[j][k];.
smaple matrix: {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
expected result:
minor:
5.000000, 6.000000,
8.000000, 9.000000,
minor:
4.000000, 6.000000,
7.000000, 9.000000,
minor:
4.000000, 5.000000,
7.000000, 8.000000,

what i get:
minor:
5.000000, 6.000000,
8.000000, 9.000000,
minor:
5.000000, 7.000000,
8.000000, 9.000000,
minor:
5.000000, 7.000000,
8.000000, 9.000000,


Could you add a sample input and the desired output?

Hint: what condition determines whether an element’s column moves or stays the same in the minor compared to the original matrix?

minor[j-1][k-1] will break the array bounds when k == 0 and i != 0.

Don't use k-1 as the index in minor. That shifts every column to the left, not just the ones after the skipped column.
You need an index variable the counts up from 0, except when you're skipping a column because i == k. So use another variable and only increment it in the if block;
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int matrixDimension = 3;
    float matrix[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    float minor[matrixDimension-1][matrixDimension-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixDimension; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < matrixDimension; j++) {
            int kminor = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixDimension; k++) {
                 if(k != i) {
                    minor[j-1][kminor] = matrix[j][k];
                    kminor++;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("minor: \n");
        printf("%f, ", minor[0][0]);
        printf("%f, \n", minor[0][1]);
        printf("%f, ", minor[1][0]);
        printf("%f, \n", minor[1][1]);
    }
}

Another option is to make the destination index conditional:
minor[j-1][k < i ? k : k-1] = matrix[j][k];

